# EC2上で起動しているWEBAPP側でクライアント側の接続元IP（グローバルIP）の取得する方法について

Tags: javascript, python3, aws, vue.js

お世話になります。
表題について、webアプリ上のとあるボタンを押した際に、
クライアント側（私）のグローバルIPを取得し、
RDSに登録を行うといったことをしたいのですが、
プログラム上に以下URLをうめこんでグローバルIPを取得しているのですが、
EC2のグローバルIP？と思われるIPが取得されてしまっている状況です。

https://api.ipify.org/?format=json

EC2上で動いているアプリ側でクライアントのグローバルIPを取得することは
不可能なのでしょうか。解決方法がございましたら、
ご教授いただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Pythonとjavascriptがタグで設定されていますが、EC2で動いているサーバサイド言語はどちらですか？どちらで取得をしたいですか？

Comment: frontendはJavaScriptを利用しています。Backend はPythonです。取得したいのはJavaScriptでの取得を想定しております。わがままで申し訳ございませんが、サンプルのコードなどもいただけると非常にありがたいです。。。

Comment: EC2でグローバルIPを取得したいと質問に書いてありますが、コメントではjavascriptで取得したいといっています。要件がぶれている印象です。改めて質問を確認してみてください

Answer (score 2):

サーバー側でクライアントのIPを取得する方法について紹介します。

EC2と言っても構成は色々あります。
ALB(ELB)を使っているか、Nginxを使っているか、Webアプリのフレームワークは何か。
そのあたりが書かれていないため、こうです、とは書けませんが、原則的なことを回答します。

アクセス元のIPアドレスはHTTPヘッダーに乗って最終的なサーバープロセスまで届きますが、途中でロードバランサーやリバースプロキシを経由するとそのサーバーのアドレスに置き換わってしまいます。そこで、元々のIPアドレスを届けるための設定などがそういった中継サーバーの設定に用意されています。

HTTPリクエストヘッダの以下の値を参照してください。

- REMOTE_ADDR

  - HTTP接続元アドレス
  - 直接接続しているときは、ブラウザでアクセスしている人のアドレスを指す
  - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3875#section-4.1.8
- X-Forwarded-For or Forwarded

  - プロキシ等サーバー経由時に元のクライアントIPを保持する
  - プロキシ等の設定によっては保持されない
  - https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For
- X-REAL-IP

  - Nginxなどで登場する設定で、使い方はネットのあちこちで言及されているが仕様が存在しない
  - [Story behind X-Forwarded-For and X-Real-IP headers - The Matrix has you...](https://distinctplace.com/2014/04/23/story-behind-x-forwarded-for-and-x-real-ip-headers/)

以下の記事が参考になります。

- [remote_addrとかx-forwarded-forとかx-real-ipとか - Carpe Diem](https://christina04.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/10/25/190000)
- [python - How do I get user IP address in django? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django)
- `X-` がつくヘッダーは標準化されていないヘッダー [HTTP ヘッダー - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)